# ItemTouchHelper in RecyclerView that has nested horizontal RecyclerView - can't scroll nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

1. `RecyclerView` uses `ItemTouchHelper` for swipe-to-dismiss
2. `ViewHolder` contains nested horizontal `RecyclerView`
3. Nested horizontal `RecyclerView` cannot be scrolled, instead whole `ViewHolder` gets swiped because `ItemTouchHelper` intercepts the swipe.

How do I make `ItemTouchHelper` ignore swipes on nested horizontal `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Hey are you saying that you want a horizontal recycler view in vertical recycler view ?

Comment: I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a `ViewHolder` which is in vertical `RecyclerView` already. So that nested horizontal RecyclerView cannot be scrolled, because `ItemTouchHelper` intercepts the swipe on it and swipes whole outer `ViewHolder`.

Comment: alright I think I have another opinion for you but first tell me about the data you are putting in recycler ? is that server data ? and also will you have more than one horizontal recycler in your item ?

Comment: Yes, it is data from a server. Lets say, it is a list of articles. One item represents an article, the nested horizontal `RecyclerView` represents a list of tags related to that articles. There only gonna be one nested `RecyclerView` per item.

Comment: Oh...

then you can just create what you have already created but I don't think it requires an ItemTouchHelper.  

you can simply create a xml file that contains full width and wrap height recycler and in your main adapter all your items have there adapter parent will be vertical and child will be horizontal.

Comment: I think you still don't understand the problem correctly. I am using `ItemTouchHelper` for swipe-to-delete an item from my outer `RecyclerView`. Yes, If I don't user `ItemTouchHelper` nested `RecyclerView` scrolls fine, that's not the problem. But I do need swipe-to-delete behavior on the outer `RecyclerView`.

Comment: sorry :P but still swipe will be horizontal and also scroll is at the same position it will mess 

have you seen such interaction already somewhere ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198213/discussion-between-sermilion-and-arbaz-pirwani).